# Stop timer if DIV value changed based on ActionResult Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I am uploading files into the folder as well as saving their details into DB. While performing this task I am starting my timer And after inserting data I am interested to STOP the timer.

```
<div id="labelUploadingStartTime" name="labelUploadingStartTime"></div>
<div id="labelUploadingEndTime" name="labelUploadingEndTime"></div>
```

Using the below function I am displaying the **START TIME** on my **labelUploadingStartTime** label.

```
function startUpdatingUploading_StartTimeIndicator() {       
        intervalIdUploadingStartTime = setInterval(
            function () {                
                $.post(
                    "/MyUpload/GetStartTime",
                    function (progress) {                        
                        $("#labelUploadingStartTime").html(progress);
                    }
                );
            },
            10
        );
    }
```

At the **same time** when the **labelUploadingStartTime** value is set in **labelUploadingEndTime** I am display the countdown details using below function.

```
function startUpdatingUploadingEndTimeIndicator() {
       $.post(  
            "/MyUpload/GetStartTime",
            function (progress) {                
                if (progress != null) {
                    intervalIdUploadingEndTime = setInterval(function () {
                        var currentTime = new Date();
                        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
                        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
                        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

                        // Add leading zeros
                        hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;
                        minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
                        seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

                        // Compose the string for display
                        var currentTimeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                        $("#labelUploadingEndTime").html(currentTimeString);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Now my interest is when data is inserted into the database I want to STOP THE TIMER and in **labelUploadingEndTime** I want to display the ending time.

For example,

labelUploadingStartTime  -- > 12:10:10

labelUploadingEndTime -- > 12:12:30

How CAN I STOP THE TIMER?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're sending a "ping" *every* 10ms?  Why are you not just waiting for the upload response to complete?  Does your "save to file and db" run asynchronously in your .net - ie return immediately and then start saving?  Or does your original POST (to upload the file(s)) only return when complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you can stop the timer with the `clearInterval()` JS function. You pass in the timer ID that you want to stop, eg:

```
clearInterval(intervalIdUploadingEndTime);
```

However, I don't think you need a timer at all for this. You can use the `success` function of `$.post` to add the finish time to the other label.

```
function doUpload() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  $("#labelUploadingStartTime").html(startTime.toLocaleString());

  $.post(
    "/MyUpload/PostFiles",
    function () {                        
      var endTime = new Date();
      $("#labelUploadingEndTime").html(endTime.toLocaleString());
    }
  );
}
```

Your backend doesn't need to return the start and end times of the file upload, you have that information on the client side

Comment: I'm *guessing* that `MyUpload/GetStartTime` will be OPs "ping" to get the current progress.  So this would need to be the original POST, eg `MyUpload/PostFiles` (or whatever OP is using).

Comment: Right, but the ping isn't even needed because the start/end times can be calculated from the client side

Comment: @nevada_scout thank you for your reply... clearInterval(intervalIdUploadingEndTime);  works for me.